# Does isRequired() conflict with onDelete(DeleteBehavior.setNull)?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am creating code first Entity framework and when I using fluent API to manage the mapping I have the following code

```
     modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                        .HasOne(r => r.Creator)
                        .WithMany(u => u.Rooms)
                        .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatorId)
                        .IsRequired()
                        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

so my question is there is any conflict in this chaining method as IsRequired() is used to make the foreign key not allowed to be null and the ".OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);" set the foreign key to null when u (referred to the user) entity is deleted, so what would be the behavior of this chaining method when the user associated with this room is deleted, is the operation will be done and the foreign will be set to null or the operation will be restricted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, they will conflict. If you use `DeleteBehavior.SetNull`, your `CreatorId` will be set to nullable during the migration. However, if you set `CreatorId` to required, they will conflict and you will not be able to successfully migrate and successfully created the relationship.

[image]

If you need the `CreatorId` attribute to be required, then it is recommended that you use：

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                    .HasOne(r => r.Creator)
                    .WithMany(u => u.Rooms)
                    .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatorId)
                    .IsRequired()
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

else,you can use:

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Room>()
                 .HasOne(r => r.Creator)
                 .WithMany(u => u.Rooms)
                 .HasForeignKey(p => p.CreatorId)
                 .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

For more details,you can see this article: [The Fluent API OnDelete Method](https://www.learnentityframeworkcore.com/configuration/fluent-api/ondelete-method).

Comment: thank you, I appreciate your trying to explain this